# using google customsearch can you sort by metatag as a number

Tags: sorting, integer, filtering, google-custom-search

I am doing a Google customsearch function in an angularjs application calling search results using ajax

I can sort the data, but it is treating the metatag values I'm using as a string rather than the number(integer) that it should be.

`data['sort']=' more:pagemap:metatags-featuredindex';`

here is an example of the meta tag

is there any way to make it treat it as an integer?
the docs are confusing and mostly talk about dates.